# How to get recent Blender version to work on Linux?

Tags: command-line, linux

**How to get latest or recent Blender (headless okay) to work on Linux ARM64?** I am using Ubuntu 22.04, but I can choose from Oracle Linux (based on Red Hat), Ubuntu 22.04, AlmaLinux, or Rocky Linux, or [create an Oracle OCI custom image](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/importingcustomimagelinux.htm#requirements)

[Arch Linux has the latest version for ARM64](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/blender).

On Ubuntu 22.04 ARM64, it is a very old version (3.0.1 available, 3.5.1 latest):

```
> sudo apt-get update
> apt-cache policy blender
blender:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.1+dfsg-7
  Version table:
     3.0.1+dfsg-7 500
> sudo snap install blender
error: snap "blender" is not available on stable for this architecture (arm64) but exists on other
       architectures (amd64).
> sudo snap install blender --classic
error: snap "blender" is not available on stable for this architecture (arm64) but exists on other
       architectures (amd64).
```

Flathub also [only supports x86_64 for Blender](https://flathub.org/apps/org.blender.Blender).

I am not able to compile from source since Embree is needed and disabling it [causes inaccurate renders](https://medium.com/@zxyvri/findings-of-running-blender-on-a-arm-cpu-aaa6ce56a4a) ("There can be some glitches we can expect since Blender on Arm linux is not natively supported. An example of this can be seen in the output of the bmw render where there is a white patch at the top right of the output").

Comment: You should pick Linux distribution for this question not to be too broad. What happens if you try `sudo snap install blender --classic` on  Ubuntu 22.04? That should work... doesn't it?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I have updated the post with the output. It does not work. Even the Snap store (https://snapcraft.io/blender) says only amd64 is supported. In the post, I have "picked" Ubuntu 22.04, but I am willing to change to an alternative.